# Volt-Sec-balance and Capacitor-Charge-balance

Tags: capacitor, inductor

I have a problem to get to an conclusion with the VS- or CC-balance.

I know that the voltage over an inductor in an switched topology behaves in an stationary state like this:

[image: VS-Balance]

So the voltage-average over one period is equal to zero.
It follows that the current-average over one period is constant.

How do i get to that conclusion? (I have the same question for the CC-balance for the behavior of the current and voltage of the capacitance)

Comment: What do you mean *same for the Capacitance*. It isn't the same.

Comment: I updated the question. I wanted to clarify that my question is the same for the CC-Balance, not that the Capacitorvoltage behaves like the Inductorvoltage

Answer (score 2):

> *So the Voltage-average over one period is equal to Zero. It follows
> that the Current-average over one period is constant.*

For an inductor \$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$.

And a simple outcome of this is that there can be no change in current if the voltage is zero.

---

Put differently, if the average voltage over a certain time period is zero then the current at the start of that period must be the same as the current at the end of that period.

However, it does not mean that the average current is zero; in fact far from it. For instance if the inductor is 1 henry and 1 volt was applied for 1 second, the current would rise to 1 amp. If you then reversed the voltage supply for one second, the current would fall from 1 amp to zero.

Hence, although the voltage average is zero, the current average is far from being zero.

> *I have the same question for the CC-Balance for the behaviour of the
> Current and Voltage of the Capacitance*

You need to unambiguously state the relationship you are trying to understand just like you did for the inductor (at the top of this answer).